# Generating function of a sequence

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

> There are n lines drawn in a plane such that no 2 lines are parallel
>   and no 3 lines are concurrent. If the plane is then divided into an regions prove
>   that
>   $$a_1=2,a_2=4,a_n=a_{n-1}+n \; \mathrm{for} \; n\ge2$$
>   Find the generating function for this sequence

Try: Starting from $a_0 = 1$, the sequence will be: $1,2,4,7,11,16,22,29,37,46,56,..... $

Therefore the generating function will be of the form $g(x) = 1+2x+4x^2+7x^3+...$

Comment: In this group, you should provide your own efforts first.  Especially in problems like this, where solutions may be found easily on the internet and in textbooks.

Comment: i have got an answer for the proof, Im just unsure on how to deduce the generating function from the sequence.

Comment: So, show us your start.  What form will your generating function have?  How do you convert $a(n)$ to $a(n-1)$ in it?  How can you handle the $+n$ in it?

Comment: starting from a0 = 1, the sequence will be: 1,2,4,7,11,16,22,29,37,46,56,.....

Comment: therefore the generating function will be of the form g(x) = 1+2x+4x^2+7x^3+...

Answer (score 1):

Suggested steps.

Begin with
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(n) x^n = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n)x^n
$$
as the OP suggests.

Next, in terms of $g$, what is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a(n-1)x^n
$$
What is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^n
$$

Put these three results together (using your recurrence $a(n)=a(n-1)+n$) to get an equation satisfied by $g$.

Solve it, to determine what $g$ actually is.

Comment: sum to infinity nx^n = 1 +2x +3x^2 +4x^3 = 1/(1-x)^2                           sum to infinity a(n-1)x^n = 1 + 2x^2 + 4x^2 + 7x^3 = ? is this not the same sequence if you start at n=1?                                   If it helps I know the answer I'm working towards is              (1-x+x^2)/(1-x)^3

Answer (score 0):

Use the recurrence backwards to get $a_0 = 1$, write the recurrence without subtraction in indices:

$\begin{equation*}
  a_{n + 1}
    = a_n + n + 1
\end{equation*}$

Define the generating function:

$\begin{equation*}
   A(z)
     = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
\end{equation*}$

Multiply the recurrence by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$:

$\begin{equation*}
  \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
    = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n
        + \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) z^n
\end{equation*}$

Recognize the sums:

$\begin{align*}
   \sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + 1} z^n
     &= \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} \\
   \sum_{n \ge 0} (n + 1) z^n
     &= \frac{d}{d z} \sum_{n \ge 0} z^n \\
     &= \frac{d}{d z} \frac{1}{1 - z} \\
     &= \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
\end{align*}$

A bit of algebra, and partial fractions, gives:

$\begin{align*}
   A(z)
     &= \frac{1 - z + z^2}{(1 - z)^3} \\
     &= \frac{1}{(1 - z)^3}
          - \frac{1}{(1 - z)^2}
          + \frac{1}{1 - z}
\end{align*}$

By the binomial theorem:

$\begin{align*}
   (1 - z)^{-m}
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^k \binom{-m}{k} z^k \\
     &= \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{m - 1 + k}{m - 1} z^k
\end{align*}$

So we have the coefficients:

$\begin{align*}
  a_n
    &= \binom{2 + n}{2} - \binom{1 + n}{1} + 1 \\
    &= \frac{(n + 2) (n + 1)}{2} - (n + 1) + 1 \\
    &= \frac{n^2 + n + 2}{2}
\end{align*}$